# Kubernetes system:serviceaccount can't access service

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-nginx-ingress-on-kubernetes-2b733d8d2f45) to setup an nginx-ingress controller.

It seems it was written before RBAC was fully integrated into k8s. When I get to the final step of running the [nginx-controller.yaml](https://gist.github.com/gokulchandra/78b7f0bf0b3a3c9d4434138cd6c6d769#file-nginx-controller-yaml) I get back an authorization error:

```
no service with name default/default-http-backend found: services "default-http-backend" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get services in the namespace "default"
```

What do I need to do to make this work with RBAC?

Comment: I would suggest using the official and latest one: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/ and also if you are using GKE, do check that your gcloud account has enough creds to do RBAC stuff. Something like $ kubectl create clusterrolebinding YOURNAME-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=YOUREMAIL@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

That hackernoon post (like most of them) is incorrent. Specifically there are no RBAC objects and the deployment is not assigned a service account (i.e.: serviceAccountName: ).

To ensure that you have the right (or enough) RBAC objects created check out the RBAC-* objects at https://github.com/mateothegreat/k8-byexamples-ingress-controller/tree/master/manifests.